# boto3 type error when enabling s3 bucket encryption

Tags: boto3

I am currently receiving this error when trying to enable server-side bucket encryption:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "expected string or bytes-like object",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/s3EncryptionCompliance.py",
      8,
      "handler",
      "response = client.put_bucket_encryption(Bucket= bucket, ContentMD5='string', ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration={'Rules': [{'ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault': {'SSEAlgorithm': 'AES256'}},]})"
    ],
    [
```

I am trying to iterate through a list of buckets and add encryption to all buckets in the list.Here is my code:
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

```
def handler(event, context):
    response = client.list_buckets()
    for bucket in response['Buckets']:
        response = client.put_bucket_encryption(Bucket= bucket, ContentMD5='string', ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration={'Rules': [{'ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault': {'SSEAlgorithm': 'AES256'}},]})
```

Thank yoU!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[list_buckets](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_buckets) returns a list of **Bucket dictionaries**. Thus to get the name in your case, you have to use `bucket["Name"]`.

Therefore, you function could be (assuming everything else is correct):

```
def handler(event, context):
    response = client.list_buckets()
    for bucket in response['Buckets']:
        response = client.put_bucket_encryption(Bucket=bucket["Name"], ContentMD5='string', ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration={'Rules': [{'ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault': {'SSEAlgorithm': 'AES256'}},]})
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you. Now I need to understand what to pass as the ContentMD5

Comment: accepted! Do you have any idea what the contentMD5 is calling for?

Comment: @aroe This is used when you want to setup SSE-C encryption. You provide MD5 hash of your key to ensure that it did not get corrupted when submitting to S3.

Comment: hmm ok I don't have access to a key and I'm not sure what to pass there OR how to get a key

Comment: @aroe `ContentMD5` is not required. You just don't provide it in your case.